# Hybris ClassNotFoundException, Failed to load declared jalo class

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm facing following errors during running integration tests (even when I try to run default generated integration test):

```
ERROR [main] (junit) [ComposedTypeRowMapper] Failed to load declared jalo class
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.RestrictionType

ERROR [main] (junit) [ComposedTypeRowMapper] Failed to load declared jalo class
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.hybris.platform.cms2.jalo.CMSPageType
```

my hybris version is 2205.9, java 17

My local.properties

```
#hac.webroot=/hac
initialpassword.admin=nimda
promotions.legacy.mode=true
```

My localextensions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hybrisconfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="resources/schemas/extensions.xsd">
    <extensions>
        <path dir="${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}" />
        <extension name="platformbackoffice" />
        <extension name="trainingextension" />
        <extension name="commercefacades" />    
        <extension name="commerceservices"/>
        <extension name="trainingbackoffice" />
        <extension name="trainingfulfilmentprocess" />
        <extension name="trainingcore" />
        <extension name="traininginitialdata" />
        <extension name="trainingfacades" />
        <extension name="trainingtest" />
        <extension name="trainingstorefront" />

    </extensions>
</hybrisconfig>
```

Comment: Have you tried running `ant clean all` before running the integration tests?

Comment: yes, I've tried ant clean all, ant initialize, ant yunitinit. Nothing helped (

Comment: Can you add: <extension name="cms2" />  to your localextention.xml and try again?

Comment: is that master tenant working fine?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by removing all generated JALO classes out of the /jalo dir

Then run ant clean all & ant update system